# How do I convert my Entity Framework SqlQuery to my entity list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Environment: VS 2017 Entity Framework 6.0

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ctx = new pubsEntities())
            {
                //this will throw an exception
                var employees = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>(@"
select * from employee;
                ").ToList();
            }
        }
    }
```

Receiving this error:

> {"The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not
>   valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types."}

Comment: I suppose that you should get a `List<string>` not a single string

Comment: Either use EF or direct SQL, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on your model (type property name, sql columns name,...).

If you want to use `SqlQuery`:

```
public class MyDTO {
    string p1 {get; set;}
    int p2 {get; set;}
    //...
}

var employees = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<MyDTO>(@"
    select someString as p1, someInt as p2 from employee").ToList();
```

Otherwise you probably have an employees table in your context:

```
var employees = ctx.Employees.ToList();
```

or

```
var employees = ctx.Employees.Where(x => x.Name == "Doe").ToList();
```

If you persist with `string`:

```
var employees = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>(
    @"select someString from employee;").ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from employee
```

Presuming that the employee table has multiple columns (id, name, dob etc), then your query will return multiple columns.

```
ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>(...)
```

This will try and project those multiple columns into a string, which is not possible, hence your error message.